# Cómo recargar un DataTables cada cierto tiempo javascript + php + html

Tags: html, datatables

Mi código html y php donde construyo mi table (table_oficinatecnica.php)

```
<div id="miLoad"> 
                <table id="mitabla" class="display">

                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="12">#</th>
                      <th>Fecha visita</th>
                      <th>Asunto</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Fecha Compromiso</th>
                      <th>Hora</th>
                    </tr>  
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>


                    <?php
                      $sql_query="SELECT * FROM oficinatecnica";
                      $result_set=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
                      $i=1;
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set))
                      {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="numeric"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                      <td class="numeric"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
                      <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row[8]; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row[9]; ?></td>


                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $i++;  
                      }
                  ?>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
               </div>
```

El siguiente es el script de DataTables (versión 1.10.13)

```
<script>
      var table;
      $(document).ready(function(){


       var table = $('#mitabla').DataTable({
          "destroy": true,
          "order": [[1, "desc"]],
          "language":{
          "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros por página",
          "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing":     "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
            "paginate": {
              "next":       "Siguiente",
              "previous":   "Anterior"
            },          
          },   
        }); 
      });
    </script>
```

cómo puedo hacer que me recargue cada 10 segundos por ejemplo, estuve intentando con una función de javaScript sobre un div que contiene la tabla llamado "miLoad"

```
<script>
  function actualizar(){
  $('#miLoad').fadeOut("slow").load('./table_oficinatecnica.php').fadeIn("slow");
  }
  setInterval( "actualizar()", 10000 );
</script>
```

El tema es que me esta cargando de nuevo otros divs doblemente, no me está respetando recargar solo el que contiene la tabla DataTables declarado en mi funcion actualizar

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haría de la siguiente forma se declara la función en javascript, en vez de destruir usted debería de limpia la tabla utilizando la función

```
t.clear();
```

en esta función me limpia todos los registro

```
<table  id="mitabla">
</table>


 function showAllNiveles_formacions(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Niveles_formacions/showAllNiveles_formacions',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          var html = '';
          var i;
        var t = $('#mitabla').DataTable();
        t.clear();
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){   
        var counter = 1;
        t.row.add( [
            data[i].id,
            data[i].nombre,       

            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; '+
            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'
        ] ).draw( true );
          }
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('No se pudo carga los datos ');
        }
      });
    }//fin de shollallpersona
```

Comment: no entiendo muy bien el código o la manera de aplicarlo al mio la verdad, agregué mi código de cómo construyo la tabla

Comment: lo que estoy utilizando es ajax, que me permite traer datos desde el servido sin la necesidad de recargar la página, recargar la pagina cada 10 segundo va a congestiona el servido y eso puede genera sobre costo, le sugiero que vea el siguiente video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUjIAnuX0Rw